# Why does mapply not return date-objects?

Tags: r

I have a function that takes a Date-object and returns one. However, when I applied the function to a data.frame column using the mapply function, I ran into problems: I didn't get Date-objects back, as expected, but numbers. Any idea how I could convert those to Date-objects? Also, I would be interested in what's happening here. Help is really appreciated!

Minimal example:

```
#Define simple function that takes a date-object and returns a date-object
add_day <- function(dat) {return(dat + 1)}

#Set up data.frame with two date-object entries in one column
df <- data.frame(Col_A = c(as.Date("01/01/00", "%m/%d/%y"), as.Date("05/02/11", "%m/%d/%y")))
#That is the desired result: give a date-object to the function, get one back
add_day(df[1, "Col_A"]) #Returns [1] "2000-01-02"
add_day(df[2, "Col_A"]) #Returns [1] "2011-05-03"

#Why does it not work here? What do I get back?
mapply(add_day, df[, "Col_A"]) #Returns [1] 10958 15097; Why? What is that?
```

Comment: Why not:  add_day(df$Col_A) #[1] "2000-01-02" "2011-05-03"? Or I suppose:  df$Col_A +1 but I'm staying with the functional application.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your function *is* returning 'dates', just not in the format you are used to. Dates are stored internally as days since [some fixed date]. (I can't remember off the top of my head which one, and varies slightly by specific format.)

If you wrap your `mapply` call in `as.Date` you'll see the output you expect.

To see what's going on here, consider that `mapply` is using `sapply` under the hood. So for example:

```
sapply(df[,1],add_day)
[1] 10958 15097
```

But remember that `sapply` by default is `unlist`ing results for convenience. If we specify `simplify = FALSE`:

```
sapply(df[,1],add_day,simplify = FALSE)
[[1]]
[1] "2000-01-02"

[[2]]
[1] "2011-05-03"
```

So when R coerced the list to a vector, the class information is dropped and only the internal storage is retained, namely the number of days since [whatever that specific date is]. And of course, `mapply` also has a `SIMPLIFY` argument that acts in the same way.

Comment: Thanks joran, that's a great explanation

Answer (score 12):

Another option is something like `sapply.preserving.attributes`:

```
sapply.preserving.attributes = function(l, ...) {
    r = sapply(l, ...)
    attributes(r) = attributes(l)
    r
}

> sapply.preserving.attributes(dates, add_day)
[1] "2000-01-02" "2011-05-03"
```

Comment: Thanks Owen, your option is a good one. I will use your function in my code.

Comment: just saw this.  Very nice function!

Answer (score 0):

Can use this single line of code after you run mapply

`df$date <- as.Date(as.numeric(df$date))`