# sapply cannot handle date correctly

Tags: r, sapply

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does mapply not return date-objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698797/why-does-mapply-not-return-date-objects)

i got the following bizzar problem, I have no problem when I conver one single string to date:

> as.Date(alldays[1])

```
[1] "3-04-20"
```

however, when I use sapply or lapply, I got a big negative number, does anyone know why it is like this? Thanks!

```
> (sapply(alldays[1:4], as.Date))


03-04-2012 02-04-2012 30-03-2012 29-03-2012


   -718323    -718688    -708492    -708857
```

---

Hi guys, i found the problem, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some replication data?

Comment: You're not using `lapply`, you're using `sapply`

Comment: It appears that somewhen between january and march you forgot how to accept answers.

Answer (score 10):

`sapply` applies `simplify2array` (see the documentation). If you look at the code of `simplify2array` you see `r <- as.vector(unlist(x, recursive = FALSE))`. `as.vector` removes all attributes (again see the documentation) including class "Date".

Use `as.Date(alldays[1:4],'%d-%m-%Y)`.

Comment: +1 for the `simplify2array` source